# How different are the manga and anime versions of Bakuman?

Tags: bakuman

I've been meaning to start watching/reading this series for some time now. However, I am unsure as to what media to choose.

**Is there many filler material in the anime?

Does the plot get better explained in the manga?

Or are they absolutely the same?** (meaning watching the anime or reading the manga will always leave me with the whole story)

If there are differences, provided that they do not compose an extensive list, please enumerate them.

Comment: I've never read the manga personally, but from what I've heard the anime didn't add much (or at least not as much as it could have), but differs mostly in how fast the story progresses (anime is slightly slower paced), and tends to over emphasize certain romantic relationships (at least more than the manga.) But then again, this is all hearsay from Google :P

Comment: I've only read a few chapters of the manga, but I thought the reason they made the anime so spread out (~75 episodes over 3 years instead of all at once) was to avoid filler.

Comment: One of the differences is about censoring: [Why was Shonen Jump called Shonen Jack in Bakuman Anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/38364)

Answer (score 1):

I've only seen the first season of the anime, but based on that I can point out that the manga didn't flesh out Mashiro & Moritaka's works. When they created a new manga the anime would usually show you most of its story, whereas the manga generally only went for a vague overview. I'm not sure how that worked out after they became serialized though.