# Why was Shonen Jump called Shonen Jack in Bakuman Anime?

Tags: bakuman

*Bakuman* was able to get permission to use a number of titles such as *One Piece*, *Naruto*, *Hunter x Hunter*, etc. The creators of the manga also work for *Jump*. Many of the characters in *Bakuman* are based on real life mangakas, assistants and editors working in *Bakuman*.

The number of times it is used is mind boggling and seem odd to me. To be honest while companies pay for product placement, *Jump* had the perfect opportunity to add its own in an in-house manga/anime?

So, why did *Bakuman* use *Jack* instead of *Jump*, when they could have used it seemingly quite easily?

For example: *Gintama* has no problem using *Jump* in its anime.

In the manga translation I read, the magazine was called *Shonen Jump*, but was changed to *Jack* in the anime.

Comment: possibly because of the usual "don't use actual titles" rule to avoid potential lawsuits, but because it's an anime about making manga, I'd say maybe it means "a big manga journal, like, you know, Shounen Jump, for example, but not just it necessarily"

Comment: Bakuman does use actual titles as well as names of their authors. It was serialized in the Shonen Jump itself. Gintama another one of Jump's manga uses the Jump name several time (not as frequently). The Manga uses Shonen Jump (Atlest the translation I read) but the anime uses Jack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Because the anime was broadcasted on NHK.**

NHK, being a [public TV channel in Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_broadcasting), doesn't allow commercial advertising.

> Much like the BBC, NHK is funded by a "receiving fee" by every Japanese household, **with no commercial advertising** and the maintenance of a position of strict political impartiality.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Their official [domestic program standard (Japanese)](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/pr/keiei/kijun/index.htm) (or, "standard policy") states this:

> **Item 12 - Advertising**
>
> 1. It's absolutely not allowed to broadcast in purpose of commercial advertising or self-advertisement marketing.
> 2. In the middle of the broadcast, when it's planned to include corporate name, personal name, occupation, firm name, or trade (brand) name, regardless if it's an essential component or unavoidable performance, they will be judged impartially and then given the decision on how to handle them.

The staffs, trying to avoid this case as best as they can, replaced some of the names with others:

- Shueisha (publisher of *Shonen Jump*) → Yueisha
- *Jump* (Shueisha's manga magazine brand) → *Jack*
- *SHOSETSU SUBARU* (Shueisha's monthly light novel magazine) → *SHOSETSU PLEIADES*
- *Margaret* (Shueisha's manga magazine) → *Magnolia*
- *Hashire! Daihatsu Tanto* (Japanese-brand car) → *Hirameki! Tanto-kun*

---

Source: [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%90%E3%82%AF%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%80%82_(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1)#.E5.9B.BA.E6.9C.89.E5.90.8D.E8.A9.9E.E3.81.AE.E5.A4.89.E6.9B.B4), [Yahoo! Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1452754479), [ひなぴし - HatenaBlog](http://www.hinapishi.com/entry/2015/08/28/111546)

<sup>P.S. another mind-boggling thing is, *One Piece* and *Naruto* were left as is in *Bakuman* anime.</sup>